# Subset data based on unique pairing

Tags: r, subset

I have a data frame (x) that looks like this:

```
Value<-c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)
Allele<-c('a','a','a','b','b')
Match<-c('b','b','c','b','b')
```

I would like to subset the data so that it only outputs values where pairs between Allele and Match don't occur more than once. In the above data set it would only output: false,a,b

I have tried:

```
x[!duplicated("Allele","Match"),]
```

But it isn't removing pairs that have more than one example of a match in the two columns -- it gives the same output as x. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: What is `x` ? Also please share `x` and the expected output after subset operation.

Comment: Isn't a,b appeared twice? Shouldn't the answer be false,a,c?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to also have `duplicated` to be considered from the reverse side

```
x[!(duplicated(x[-1])|duplicated(x[-1], fromLast = TRUE)),]
#   Value Allele Match
#3 FALSE      a     c
```

---

Also, the syntax in the OP's code by quoting the column names won't work.  We need to subset the dataset

```
x[c("Allele", "Match")]
```

and then apply the `duplicated` on the subset of columns

```
duplicated(x[c("Allele", "Match")])
```

#### data

```
x <- data.frame(Value, Allele, Match)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
The first bit of code you gave fixed the issue, but I can't say I understand exactly what it's doing. Even after reading the help file on duplicated() I don't understand what "looking from the reverse side" means or does differently or why you have the duplicated code in there twice. Finally: Can you explain why my syntax is wrong? I know that's a lot of questions -- explanations on anything will be appreciated! I'm a bit of a neophyte. Thanks!

Comment: @Ascaris  Lets say if we have a vector `v1 <- c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3)`.  The intention is to get only the values that are not duplicated i.e. 2 here (same as in your question). `i1 <- duplicated(v1)` returns TRUE values for every duplicate i.e. the 1st element is FALSE. `i2 <- duplicated(v1, fromLast = TRUE)` does the evaluation from the last element.  When we combine both with `|`, TRUE|FALSE returns TRUE, or FALSE/TRUE returns TRUE getting our expected output

Comment: @Ascaris your syntax is wrong because if you do `duplicated("v1")` as a string,it is checking the string  "v1" is duplicated and not the value stored in that v1.  I guess you got it

Answer (score 1):

You can group on `Allele, Match` and remove rows of groups containing more than 1 rows. A solution using `dplyr` can be as:

```
library(dplyr)

x %>% group_by(Allele, Match) %>%
  filter(n()<2) %>%
  as.data.frame()

#   Value Allele Match
# 1 FALSE      a     c
```

**Data:**

```
Value<-c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)
Allele<-c("a","a","a","b","b")
Match<-c("b","b","c","b","b")

x <- data.frame(Value, Allele, Match, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```